# OpenCV findContour giving weird results

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to put a simple bounding box over a depth image:

```
void cropAndResize(const cv::Mat &input, cv::Mat &output) {
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::Rect croppedHand;

    cv::findContours(input, contours,CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);




    int maxCont = -1;
        if (contours.size() != 0) {
            maxCont = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            int currSize = contours.at(i).size();
            if (contours.at(maxCont).size() < currSize)
                maxCont = i;
        }



        if (maxCont > -1) {
            croppedHand = cv::boundingRect(contours.at(maxCont));
        }
}
```

boundingRect gives me an assertion failure (points.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (points.depth() == CV_23F || points.depth() == CV_32S)) in cv::boundingRect...).

This is weird because I'm pretty sure this code has worked before. So I checked the contents of `contours` and the result was confusing. Some of the elements are vectors with size=452126096252493236 or even bigger. Checking the vector, I have mainly Points like so {x=???, y=???}.

Is there something wrong with findCountours? I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8 Pro, OpenCV 2.4.8.

Edit: Input image is CV_8UC1.

Comment: Did you check your input image? maybe you are using a wrong image !?

Comment: Pretty sure the image is correct. I displayed it before calling this function. Even if the input image is wrong, this behavior of findContours is odd

Comment: Sounds like contours was never initialized, which means there is a problem with the input. It is doubtful that there is an issue with findContours. You should check your input and make sure it is right. That behavior is expected (not odd) when the VS debugger is trying to read a uninitialized variable.

Comment: I guarantee you the input is not wrong. Î will show it in an edit of my question. Please check it.

Comment: maybe because I'm using const everywhere and put in the same matrix as output?

Comment: Why is that a problem? I'm using the code supplied here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way

Comment: Findcontours is definitely bugged, or at least my version of it is. I've copy pasted the tutorial found here http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html and get the same weird error. Guess I have to recompile OpenCV...again. This library is beginning to be a huge pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else having this problem, I solved it by going back to VS2010. Seems like OpenCV is inept at keeping up with current technology.

Comment: Were you using VS2013 compiled opencv? Remember you can not mix Visual Studio compilers without isolating the allocations and deallocations.